# Alternate table row background-color, restarting with every tbody

Tags: jquery

I can add a background to alternating rows in a  table like this:

```
$(".myTbl tr:even td").css("background-color", "#f5f5f5");
```

However, if I have multiple instances of  withing the same table I would like it to restart with each set. for some reason the following code did not work:

```
$("tbody tr:even td").css("background-color", "#f5f5f5");
```

P.S. Using jQuery to appease older IE browsers...

Comment: remove `td` in the selector if you want it by row..

Answer (score 1):

Here, use this

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
      $("table tbody tr:even").css("background-color", "#F4F4F8");
      $("table tbody tr:odd").css("background-color", "#EFF1F1");
    });
```